# Tracking managed dependency versions in Maven

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Say I have a complex project with lots of dependencies. The versions of the dependencies are managed by lots of import scope poms. My project has a dependency on artifact `group:artifact`, which has a dependency on artifact `group:transitive-dependency`. When I run `dependency:tree` I see something like this:

```
+- group:artifact:jar:1.3
   +- group:transitive-dependency:jar:1.1 (version managed from 1.3)
```

The problem is `group:artifact:1.3` requires `group:transitive-dependency` version 1.3 or higher. Sure one of the import poms is forcing the wrong version. But is there any way to know which one is, other than searching through all of them?

Comment: Have you tried running `mvn site` on your parent proejct and looking at the `dependency convergence` output?

Comment: The transitive dependency does not appear in the dependency convergence report. Nor does it show where dependencies are managed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try the maven-enforcer-plugin and configure it to do DependencyConvergence, e.g.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce</id>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <DependencyConvergence/>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

That will show you which top level dependencies have different versions of other dependencies in their dependency trees. You then suppress the dependency variants that you don't want using exclusions.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when 2 or more parent Poms conflicting with a same artifact.

E.g.:

```
[INFO] |  \- com.rbs.gbm.risk:framework-core:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.rbos.gbm.risk:log4jextensions:jar:2.3:compile (version managed from 2.2)
[INFO] |     +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
```

In my case, framework-core has log4jextentsions 2.2 mentioned. And my super-pom says log4jextentsions 2.3. Somehow the framework-core convinced maven to use log4jextentsions 2.2.

Later when I update framework-core pom to use 2.3:

```
[INFO] |  \- com.rbs.gbm.risk:framework-core:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.rbos.gbm.risk:log4jextensions:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
```