# Importing pom in dependency management

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, dependency-management

Reading from the [doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) ,

> 1. Do not attempt to import a pom that is defined in a submodule of the current pom. Attempting to do that will result in the build
>      failing since it won't be able to locate the pom.
> 2. Never declare the pom importing a pom as the parent (or grandparent, etc) of the target pom. There is no way to resolve the
>      circularity and an exception will be thrown.
> 3. When referring to artifacts whose poms have transitive dependencies the project will need to specify versions of those artifacts as
>      managed dependencies. Not doing so will result in a build failure
>      since the artifact may not have a version specified. (This should be
>      considered a best practice in any case as it keeps the versions of
>      artifacts from changing from one build to the next).

I have the following doubt:

a) What does point 3 mean ?

b) In 1st point , why would maven not able to find the sub module pom ? Is not submodule build before the parent ?

---

In point 3 , I need more clarity on `...When referring to artifacts whose poms have transitive dependencies the project will need to specify versions of those artifacts as managed dependencies...`.

So, let us say we have `project A` which we will be imported in our `project B` `<dependencyManagement>` section . Now the people who created project A have to mention versions of all transitive dependencies (not direct) of project A in its `<dependencyManagement>` section ? How can anybody know those versions for all transitive dependencies of project A ?

---

I got another doubt with point 1. I created basically an skeletal project with a super module and sub module with basically no java code. I will hence share their poms. We will see that build gets successful while this should not be the case according to point 1.

The project structure is as follows :

[image]

The pom of super module is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>my-project</name>
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <modules>
        <module>./sub-module1/pom.xml</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.home</groupId>
                <artifactId>sub-module1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

The pom for sub module is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>sub-module1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When I do `mvn clean compile` , it builds fine.

Also, I see that even if sub module pom packaging type be kept as jar, scope import does not throw error. It still compiles fine.

---

---

For future readers I will summarize the answer. Both points 1 and 2 holds true but it will give error only when POM1 (parent or super module) imports POM2 (sub module or child module) and then POM2 needs POM1 for resolution of dependencies.

In point 1 , this won't be found. In point 2 , it will be found due to inheritance but will create a cycle.

Below I give example so that people can verify.

Super module POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>my-project</name>
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <modules>
        <module>./sub-module1/pom.xml</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.home</groupId>
                <artifactId>sub-module1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Sub Module POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>sub-module1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: The first point means that you should never do a `<scope>import</scope>` inside a project which is already defined as a submodule which means is listed one `<module>..</module>` entry. cause the resolution of the import scope will be done before the rest which will result in a fail of the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> b) In 1st point , why would maven not able to find the sub module pom ? Is not submodule build before the parent ?

The submodule is not installed/deployed in a GAV referential (your maven cache or a remote Nexus repo)

That means any project which would reference a submodule pom would not find said pom in a submodule GAV, since what was built, installed and deployed was the main project GAV.

As [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) adds in the comments:

> You should never do a `<scope>import</scope>` inside a project which is already defined as a submodule which means is listed one `<module>..</module>` entry. Because the resolution of the import `scope` will be done before the rest which will result in a fail of the build.

And:

> a) What does point 3 mean ?

It means the `<dependencies>` section should declare some `<dependency>` with only `<group>` and `<artifact>`, *not* `<version>`.
The version will be fetched from the imported `<dependencyManagement>`.
See also "[Tracking managed dependency versions in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14319018/6309)".
As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31711721/6309), managed dependency is used to lock the version at the parent pom.

Comment: Of course it's not installed and should never during a build of a multi module build.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC , I have edited the question to make it more clear. Please have a look.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin If a project A is imported/declared in the dependenciesManagement section of project B,  the people who created project A have nothing to do.  The people who will *use* project A in B (or B submodules) will simply declare A in their dependencies, without A version, because the dependenciesManagement section of project B will provide that version.

Comment: @VonC , regarding point 1, I just imported pom of a sub module in its super module pom and ran the build and all was fine ? How is that possible ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin Did you import it with `<scope>import</scope>`?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin A parent project does not need to import poms of its modules: it just list the name of the modules projects.

Comment: @VonC , I meant in `<dependencyManagement>` section of super module , I am importing the sub module pom. According to point 1 , build should fail. But it is successful.  Of course , i am setting the relationship between the modules by using `<modules>` tag in super module.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin I would need to see how you did that import exactly, to know if this is anormal.

Comment: @VonC , added the details. Please have a look

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin As mentioned in http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope, This scope is only supported on a dependency of type pom in the <dependencyManagement> section. It indicates the dependency to be replaced with the effective list of dependencies in the specified POM's <dependencyManagement> section. Since they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin  I suspect if you import a submodule GAV into its parent project, it will be ignored, since the submodule GAV specifies its attributes (GAV) at the beginning of the submodule pom.xml. But if you were to import/declare it in *another* project pom dependenciesManagement, then this would fail.

Comment: @VonC Thanks. That makes sense. But what about point 2 ? If I make submodule as child of super module , still build is fine. Is not point 2 telling us that a parent module cannot import a child module pom ? May be I am not understanding some thing here.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin I suppose in this small example, the effective pom does not need to actually import that dependency, because none of the dependencies (not dependenciesManagement but dependencies) explicitly. This is all about effective pom: if, for computing the effective pom, P1 needs P2 pom which needs P1 pom... that would fail.

Comment: @VonC  thanx got it. I created an example like u said and it gave an cycle